# REGEX: Select the text between certain words, only from the file that contains a certain word

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

good day. I have to select some text between the words `start` and `finnish` in several html files. But, also, I need to select that particular text only if the file contains the word BABY SIN

For example:

> Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in
> laying out print, graphic or web designs, of a BABY SIN mark. The
> passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who
> is thought to have START scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus
> Bonorum et Malorum for use in a FINNISH type specimen book.

I made a regex, but something is not very good.

`(?s)(.*\b(BABY SIN)\b.*)\K(?s)(START).*(FINNISH)`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is `BABY SIN` always **before** `START...FINISH`? Do you want to select `START` and `FINISH` or not?

Comment: BABY SIN can be located anywhere in the file. And if BABY SIN is in the file, then to select text between `START` and `FINNISH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds the sentence even when `BABY SIN` is **after**

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(?=.*\bBABY SIN\b).*?\KSTART.*FINNISH`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?=.*\bBABY SIN\b)  # positive lookahead, make sure we have "BABY SIN" somewhere in the file
.*?                 # 0 or more any character, not greedy
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
START               # literally
.*                  # 0 or more any character
FINNISH             # literally
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: thanks, works fine. But works without .matches newsline

Comment: @RobRob: If you don't want to match `START` and `FINISH`, use: `(?=.*\bBABY SIN\b).*?START\K.*(?=FINNISH)`

Comment: @RobRob: `. matches newline` is strictly equivalent to `(?s)`

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your regex a little bit. Try the following: `(?s)(.*\b(BABY SIN)\b.*)\K(?s)(?<=START).*(?=FINNISH)`

[image]